# Does Virtual Environment changes access permissions globally?

Tags: linux, permissions, virtualenv

I have changed some files' user permissions through Linux terminal using `chmod`. I just realized that I was working in a virtual environment throughout. Does this mean that the changes have been reflected only within the environment or outside as well?

Do I have to do it again outside the environment?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python virtual environments are not virtual machines or containers, they do not protect the host OS outside of the environments. Activation of an environment just prepends its `bin/` to `$PATH` in the current terminal, nothing fancy.

You can do anything (including `chmod`) with any file outside of any environment even if an environment is activated.